# Dimensionality of the set of linear maps between inner product spaces

Tags: linear-transformations, inner-products

Suppose we have two inner product spaces $V$ and $W$ with dimensions $n$ and $m$, respectively. For some set $\{ \mathbf{v}_i\}_{i=1}^k \in V$ and some nonzero $\mathbf{w} \in W$, where $1 \leq k \leq n$, we let the subspace $U \subset L(V,W)$ be the set of linear maps $T$ between these inner products spaces such that $\langle T \mathbf{v}_i, \mathbf{w} \rangle = 0$.

Now, if that set $\{ \mathbf{v}_i\}_{i=1}^k$ happens to be linearly independent, then what can we say about the dimension of $U$? Is there a range of values that $U$ can take, or is there a unique value? Moreover, I wonder what does it mean, intuitively, for $U$ to have a dimension?

I'm not quite sure where to begin with any of these questions, so any prods in the right direction or heuristic explanations would be helpful.

Comment: The condition $\langle Tv_i,w \rangle =0$ is just equivalent to $\text{im}T\subseteq w^{\perp}$, the orthogonal complement to the span of $w$ in $W$. From here you can make some simple dimensionality arguments.

Comment: @Tom I have that $\text{rank } T = m-1$, but I am not sure how to go about finding the nullity so that I can utilize the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: For general $L(V, W)$, a basis is formed by fixing bases $(v_1, \ldots, v_m)$ of $V$ and $(w_1, \ldots, w_n)$ of $W$, and defining linear maps indexed by $(i, j) \in [m] \times [n]$ such that $v_i = w_j$, and $v_k$ maps to $0$ for every other $k \neq i$. With standard bases, this produces the standard matrix basis. Here, you just need to ensure that the vectors in your subspace of $V$, spanned by $v_1, \ldots, v_k$, map into $\{w\}^\perp$, a subspace of $W$. So, start with bases for each of your spaces, extend them, and build suitable linear maps, as above.

Comment: @TheoBendit Once I find the dimensions for those bases, how does that produce the dimension of $U$?

Comment: You build the basis of $U$ in much the same way as $L(V, W)$, i.e. by mapping a single vector from the basis of $V$ to vector in the basis of $W$, and mapping all other basis vectors to $0$. However, you just need to make sure that $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ *only* map to the part of the basis that spans $\{w\}^\perp$. It just slightly restricts your options. I won't come up with the formula in terms of the dimensions, since you should do some of the legwork yourself, but the formula is not complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, on your question about dimension of $U$: since $L(V,W)$ is a vector space, we can do usual vector space things (finding a basis, finding its dimension, etc.). This of course goes for its subspaces, including $U$.

Now, note that $\langle Tv_i, w \rangle =0$ is equivalent to $T(\text{Span}(\{v_i\}))\subseteq \{w\}^{\perp}$. We are searching for the subspace $U\subset L(V,W)$ of linear maps that send the subspace $\text{Span}(\{v_i\})\subset V$, having dimension $k$, to the subspace $\{w\}^{\perp}\subset W$, having dimension $m-1$. Note that such a map $T$ need not have rank equal to $m-1$, only $<m$; in fact, $T=0$ works fine.

The final steps are not hard, but I'll hide them in case you'd like to do them yourself.

> The problem now is just combinatorial. Let $V_1 =\text{Span}(\{v_i\})\subset V$ and $V_2 = V_1^{\perp}$. There are $k(m-1)$ dimensions of linear maps sending $V_1$ into $\{w\}^{\perp}$ (since they have dimension $k$ and $m-1$, respectively), and $(n-k)m$ dimensions of linear maps sending $V_2$ into $W$ (for the same reason), so there are $k(m-1)+(n-k)m$ dimensions of maps from $V$ to $W$ doing both. That is, $\text{dim}\ U=k(m-1)+(n-k)m=mn-k$.

An afterthought (kept in a spoiler):

> An intuitive way to view this might be that we removed $k$ dimensions of $L(V,W)$ by restricting the image of $V_1$ (having dimension $k$) by one dimension. This generalises easily: restricting the image any $k$-dim subspace of $V$ to some $l$-dim subspace of $W$ (and thus excluding $(m-l)$ dimensions) reduces the space of valid linear maps by $k(m-l)$ dimensions. This property "stacks": applying it to disjoint subspaces of $V$ applies the equivalent dimensionality reductions independently, and they sum. The proof of this is not hard and may be a fun exercise, depending on your idea of fun.

Comment: @AnneBauval Good call - swapped to $V_1^{\perp}$. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint1. If $B=(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ is a basis of $V$, prove that the map
$$U\to(w^\perp)^k\times W^{n-k},\;T\mapsto(T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n))$$
is an isomorphism.

Hint2. Justify that $(w^\perp)^k\times W^{n-k}$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb R^{m-1})^k\times(\Bbb R^m)^{n-k}=\Bbb R^d$, where $d=k(m-1)+(n-k)m=mn-k$.

Edit. Alternatively and more directly, if moreover $C=(w_1,\dots,w_m)$ is a basis of $W$ such that $w_2,\dots,w_m\perp w$, check that the canonical isomorphism
$$L(V,W)\xrightarrow{\sim} M_{m,n}(\Bbb R),\;T\mapsto[T]^B_C$$
maps $U$ onto the subspace of matrices whose $k$ first entries on the first line are $0$ (the dimension of this subspace is obviously $mn-k$).

Comment: I have solved the problem based on hints from other answers/comments, but I will surely be attempting this method, as well. It seems very elegant and much akin to something with which I am familiar...